# Android MediaPlayer stops palyng form assetst after changing image on button from assets

Tags: android, audio, mp3, assets

I have problem with playing mp3 from asset folder. When i try to change image on button, mp3 stops playing(not always...)
Error that im getting

> W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(enableMusic){
        playMusic();
    }
...


private void playMusic() {
    boolean noAudioFile = false;
    Context context = this; // or ActivityNotification.this
    MediaPlayer mpMusic = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetManager mg2 = getResources().getAssets();
    String musicPath = langFolder+audioFolder+"system/Bubble_Bath.mp3";
    try {
        mg2.open(musicPath);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        noAudioFile = true;
    }

    if(!noAudioFile) {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
        try {
            descriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(musicPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
        long end = descriptor.getLength();
        try {
            mpMusic.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{

    }
    mpMusic.setVolume(5,5);
    try {
        mpMusic.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mpMusic.start();
    mpMusic.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });


}


public void nextCard(View view) throws IOException {
    i++;
    if (i==files.length) i=0;
    if(i>-1){
        Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setText("Next");
    }
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(categoryPath+"/"+files[i]+".png"), null);
    findViewById(R.id.btnImage).setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    if(files[i].substring(0,1).contains("a") || files[i].substring(0,1).contains("i")){
        startFileSound = langFolder + audioFolder + "system/GAME_thisisan.mp3";
    }
    else if (files[i].substring(files[i].length()-1,files[i].length()).contains("s")){
        startFileSound = langFolder + audioFolder + "system/GAME_theseare.mp3";
    }
    else{
        startFileSound = noAudioFileSound;
    }
}
```

When i'll try to comment line below, mp3 is playing with no problem.

> Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(categoryPath+"/"+files[i]+".png"), null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are loading drawable from asset folder, that is correct. But Don't do in the main thread. Try to do this in different thread.

Comment: Starting music in another thread helped:)
Thank You for advice

`Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int p = 0;
                while (p != 1) {
                    mpMusic.start();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
`

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever create `MediaPlayer` like this
    `MediaPlayer mpMusic = new MediaPlayer();`

Use

```
        MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.music);
```

Comment: I wanna to use assets folder. This is only way that i can find to work with assets folder

Comment: @RobertRupa did you try to load `Bitmap` in another thread? Maybe `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 0):

try close descriptor

```
mpMusic.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
descriptor.close();
```

Comment: After close descriptor, problem still exist.